# Bootstrap mobile nav not working and footer too long

Tags: css

I don't have enough time to figure out why the mobile nav isn't working, and why the footer is too long.

Site can be found here [link removed]

Comment: Remove `height:100%` from `#footer`

Comment: Remove `height:55px` from `#ubBanner` and `height:100%` from `#footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove footer height:100% from your main.css file.

```
 #footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #005bbb;
    color: white;
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix your footer, in your main.css file (line 296), make this change

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #005bbb;
    color: white;
    font-size: x-small;
    /* height: 100%; */  <-- delete this line
}
```

I am not sure about the 'navbar in mobile' issue

Answer (score 0):

For the footer remove in your css "height:100%;" and your nav is working you don't have any background to the .navbar-nav class.

```css
.navbar-nav {
    background: #005bbb;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following css,
add background color to your mobile nav menu:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
        background: #757575!important;
    }
}
```